combining multiple stocks prices sprarklines into single sparkline from googlesheet
I am trying to combine multiple sparkline generated from Google finance with this code
=SPARKLINE(QUERY({GOOGLEFINANCE("AMZN","price",TODAY()-365,TODAY(),"daily"),GOOGLEFINANCE("MSFT","price",TODAY()-365,TODAY(),"daily")},"select Col1, Col2+Col4",1))

and now I want to add stock quantity to this code like
"AMZN"=25qty, "MSFT"=30qty

